# Extracting the year from an 8 digit int (ddmmyyyy)

Tags: c

I have an 8 digit `int` that stores a date. For example `12041989` is 12 April 1989. What type of variable should I declare the date and how do I extract the year?

Edit: With what you have told me, I did it like this: (I have to calculate a persons age by inputing the current date and his date of birth)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
   unsigned int a, b, ac, an, c;
   printf("\n Current date zzllaaaa \n");
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("\n Date of birth zzllaaaa \n");
   scanf("%d", &b);
   ac = a % 10000;
   an = b % 10000;
   c = ac - an;
   printf("\n Age is: %d", c);
   getch();
}
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't and I can't get it why. For example for `13102013` and `12061995` it tells me that the age is `-3022`. Why is that?

Comment: If you try anything,post your code.

Comment: This question should not be closed. Although OP did't posted the code but **he is not asking for code**. He is only querying about variable to store date and how to extract digits (year) from that variable. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Puh lease. This may be obvious to you, it may be in chapter 1 of your intro programming textbook (although it's probably not), but that doesn't mean the asker has easy access to the answer. Show some basic courtesy.

Comment: Asking for a type and a method on how to accomplish something is technically asking for code. Yes, I know, it's not a "Gimme teh code plz" question, but I also don't see it as a good question for a wide audience. It is unlikely that anyone else will ever stumble on it and needs the same kind of advice. It's not a bad question, but it isn't one that fits perfectly on this platform. Anyway, I think with the answers provided so far, it is fairly unnecessary to reopen it.

Comment: @maxx You're using `unsigned` integers. Replace `unsigned int` with `int` and it should work fine.

Comment: With the edit by the OP, I'd suggest reopening the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about dates with 5 or more digits for the year, you can use the modulo operator:

```
int date = 12041989;
int year = date % 10000;
```

The type `int` is usually 32 bits wide on most machines. This is enough for storing dates of format "ddmmyyyy" in a single number. I'd discourage you of using `unsigned int`, as the difference of two dates might be negative on purpose (E.g. if you accidentally put the date of birth first and the current date second, you will get a negative age and with that you've detected an error in the input).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() // better use int main(), as void main is only a special thing not supported by all compilers.
{
   int a, b, ac, an, c; // drop the "unsigned" here.
   printf("\n Current date zzllaaaa \n");
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("\n Date of birth zzllaaaa \n");
   scanf("%d", &b);
   ac = a % 10000;
   an = b % 10000;
   c = ac - an;
   if ( c < 0 )
   {
       printf("You were born in the future, that seems unlikely. Did you swap the input?\n");
   }
   printf("\n Age is: %d", c);
   getch();
}
```

Comment: +1, but do not give answers for questions asked directly without making single try.

Comment: @Gangadhar I disagree. I agree with the close (that's why I voted), but there's hardly any effort to write down these three lines and helping someone. The question does not fit the requirements of this platform, but that does not mean it shouldn't be answered if possible.

Comment: @Downvoter, please leave a comment to give me the chance of improving my answer.

Comment: If you voted to close - why did you answer? If you answered - why vote to close?

Comment: @littleadv I gave an explanation on why I did that in a previous comment on this answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw, mid-air collision:) However, I would argue that if you vote to close the question - it is because it doesn't fit the concept. We do not want to encourage people to post unfit questions, answering - encourages.

Comment: @littleadv The close itself is a pretty clear sign itself on what's fit or unfit. Beeing helpful is (in my opinion) a different thing than keeping the platform "clean". I just said "Hey, please try better next time (we'll close this one), but here's how you'd do it". I guess this would be a discussion for meta, but I'm not really interested in arguing about it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use modulo operator (`%`) to extract digits from a number.

```
int date = 12041989;
int day,month,year;

year = date%10000;
date = date/10000;
month = date/100;
date = date/100;
day  = date;
```

Comment: +1, but do not give answers for questions asked directly without making single try.

Comment: @Gangadhar; Agreed. But he was not asking for code. Most probably he just want to know how to extract digits from a number (use of modulo operator).